# Representing a von Neumann measurement as $[\mathcal{I} \otimes P_i] U(\rho_s \otimes \rho_a)U^{-1} [\mathcal{I} \otimes P_i]$, how do we choose $U$?

Tags: measurement, textbook-and-exercises, quantum-operation

Given the state of a system as $\rho_s$ and that of the ancilla (pointer) as $\rho_a$, the Von-Neumann measurement involves entangling a system with ancilla and then performing a projective measurement on the ancilla. This is often represented as
$$[\mathcal{I} \otimes P_i] U(\rho_s \otimes \rho_a)U^{-1} [\mathcal{I} \otimes P_i],$$
where $\mathcal{I}$ is the identity on system space, $P_i$ is the projector corresponding to $i$-th outcome, and $U$ is the combined unitary.

My question: How to choose the form of $U$?

Comment: are you asking given a map $\Phi$ represented as $\Phi(\rho)=\operatorname{tr}_a[U(\rho\otimes \rho_a)U^\dagger]$, how to find the unitary $U$ in this representation?

Comment: Actually, a simple example would be sufficient.

Comment: a simple example of what?

Comment: An example of U, that would lead to a valid measurement.

Comment: I am asking the following: Given the combined state $\rho_s \otimes \rho_a$, give an example (or a general form) of $U$, such that the quantity I wrote in my question, represents a valid measurement.